# S Curves, Comparing where you should be and where you are

Tags: evm, schedule

If you are using Earned Value, you can create an S Curve that shows your planned value across time.  As you add actuals and take earnings, you can show the AC curve and EV curve and compare it visually with the PV curve, as well as calculate your indices.

If you are not doing Earned Value, is there way to create similar curves using Work values instead in MS Project?

The project is an IV&V type effort where the vendor is contracted firm fixed price.  As such, true dollar values will not be known to the IV&V vendor.  Only schedule data is visible.  The schedule is baselined and they are capturing work percent complete as their method and finish variance is known.

Thanks for the help.  Julie??

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay - I usually only follow questions tagged with MS Project.

Do you have access to actual work values and baseline work?  A suggestion is to assign all resources at $1 per hour.  Using those values, you can still get somewhat meaningful EV measures as 1 hour work = $1. (or whatever currency).

Comment: I do have actual work values.  They are using work % complete as the method of capturing progress, which I don't care for.  Okay, I'll add currency.  If I did that, can I also do Earned Schedule analysis?  I should be able to, right?

Comment: As long as you have: costed resources (using $1 per hour will do) assigned to tasks, accurate baselines, recorded progress (% work complete), and a status date - you can generate Earned Value data.